# Query optimisation for FK association on inherited model from the base model

Tags: django, django-models, orm, multi-table-inheritance

I have users who create (or receive) transactions. The transaction hierarchy I have is a multi-table inheritance, with `Transaction` as the base model containing the common fields between all transaction types, such as User (FK), amount, etc. I have several transaction types, which extend the `Transaction` model with type specific data.

For the sake of this example, a simplified structure illustrating my problem can be found below.

```
from model_utils.managers import InheritanceManager

class User(models.Model):
    pass

class Transaction(models.Model):
    DEPOSIT = 'deposit'
    WITHDRAWAL = 'withdrawal'
    TRANSFER = 'transfer'

    TYPES = (
        (DEPOSIT, DEPOSIT),
        (WITHDRAWAL, WITHDRAWAL),
        (TRANSFER, TRANSFER),
    )

    type = models.CharField(max_length=24, choices=TYPES)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    objects = InheritanceManager()

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['user']),
            models.Index(fields=['type'])
        ]

class Withdrawal(Transaction):
    TYPE = Transaction.WITHDRAWAL
    bank_account = models.ForeignKey(BankAccount)

class Deposit(Transaction):
    TYPE = Transaction.DEPOSIT
    card = models.ForeignKey(Card)

class Transfer(Transaction):
    TYPE = Transaction.Transfer
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['recipient'])
        ]
```

I then set each transaction's type in the inherited model's `.save()` method. This is all fine and well.

The problem comes in when I would like to fetch the a user's transactions. Specifically, I require the sub-model instances (deposits, transfers and withdrawals), rather than the base model (transactions). I also require transactions that the user both created themselves AND transfers they have received. For the former I use `django-model-utils`'s fantastic `IneritanceManager`, which works great. Except that when I include the filtering on the transfer submodel's recipient FK field the DB query increases by an order of magnitude.

As illustrated above I have placed indexes on the Transaction `user` column and the Transfer `recipient` column. But it appeared to me that what I may need is an index on the Transaction subtype, if that is at all possible. I have attempted to achieve this effect by putting an index on the Transaction `type` field and including it in the query, as you will see below, but this appears to have no effect. Furthermore, I use `.select_related()` for the user objects since they are required in the serializations.

The query is structured as such:

```
from django.db.models import Q

    queryset = Transaction.objects.select_related(
         'user',
         'transfer__recipient'
    ).select_subclasses().filter(
         Q(user=request.user) |
         Q(type=Transaction.TRANSFER, transfer__recipient=request.user)
    ).order_by('-id')
```

So my question is, why is there an order of magnitude difference on the DB query when including the `Transfer.recipient` in the query? Have I missed something? Am I doing something silly? Or is there a way I can optimise this further?

Comment: Can you try filtering before calling select_subclasses? Because the way this query is constructed, it could be selecting subclasses for all items Transaction model before applying filters

Comment: Hi @OzgurAkcali, thank you for your suggestion. I tried moving both select_related() and select_subclasses() to the end of the query, after filtering, but this appears to have no effect. I didn't realise the ordering here mattered.